# Pass table name as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass the table name as parameter and get all columns size of that table altered by column length + 50.

```
alter PROCEDURE dbo.testsp
  @tablename varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
@totalWeight TABLE (columnnames nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO @totalWeight (columnnames)
SELECT name FROM sys.columns
 WHERE object_id = object_id(@tablename);
END
GO
```

Comment: you want to increase the column size by 50 chars ? Is this a one time effort or you are going to do this on regular basis ?

Comment: i have almost 300 tables

Comment: i want to check max(length) of each column and alter column by max(length) + 50 chars

Comment: it is not as simple as that. You need to check for data type. You only alter for string data type. And If you have any constraint on the table like primary key or foreign key, you can't just perform a `alter column` like that. You will need to drop the constraint, alter the column and then re-create the constraints. Things gets even more complicated if you have foreign key constraints, you need to alter both end of the column before add back the constraint

Comment: gee squirrel, thats awfully true

Answer (score 2):

This query returns your alteration statements in the last column. You can then run them through dynamic sql.

```
SELECT 
    tbl.name 'Table Name',
   c.name 'Column Name',
   t.name,  
   c.max_length 'Max Length in Bytes',
   c.precision ,
   c.scale ,
   c.is_nullable,
   q1.*,
       'alter table ['
       +tbl.name
       +'] alter column ['
       +c.name
       +'] '
       +t.name
       +'('+
       convert(nvarchar(1000),  CASE WHEN t.name IN ('nchar','nvarchar') THEN  c.max_length/2 ELSE c.max_length END +50)
       +') '
        + case c.is_nullable when 0 then ' not null' else ' null' end
    as 'Alteration statement'
FROM    
   sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
   sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
inner join sys.tables tbl on tbl.object_id=c.object_id
CROSS APPLY
(
    select
        t.name +
        CASE WHEN t.name IN ('char', 'varchar','nchar','nvarchar') THEN '('+

                    CASE WHEN c.max_length=-1 THEN 'MAX'

                        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),

                                    CASE WHEN t.name IN ('nchar','nvarchar')

                                    THEN  c.max_length/2 ELSE c.max_length END )

                        END +')'

                WHEN t.name IN ('decimal','numeric')

                        THEN '('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),c.precision)+','

                                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),c.Scale)+')'

                        ELSE '' END
        + case c.is_nullable when 0 then ' not null' else ' null' end
        as [DDL name before]
)q1
where t.name IN ('char', 'varchar','nchar','nvarchar') and c.max_length>-1
```

Comment: i want to find max(length) of each nvarchar column by passing table name and alter that column with +50 chars

Comment: the statement is right there in the last column. Do you need help for the dynamic sql and the cursor part, too?

Comment: suppose a column length is nvarchar(200).. and data in that column is 20 char. i want a script which give alter statement like nvarchar(70).... maximum data length of that column + 50 char

Answer (score 0):

Run the following example of query, it creates a bunch of ALTER statements. Copy-paste the result into a new query window and run it again. Add other data types from `sys.types` if need.

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' +
       c.name + '] ' + ty.name + '(' + CAST(c.max_length + 50 AS nvarchar(10)) + ') ' +
       CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END + ';'
FROM sys.tables t 
     INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
     INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE t.type = 'U' AND
      c.system_type_id IN (167 /*varchar*/, 231 /*nvarchar*/)
```

Comment: i want something like this...SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' +
       column_name + '] ' + '(' + CAST((SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH('+ COLUMN_NAME+ ' + 50 ) + ')' 
       
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS